# Transferring from phd to masters

Tags: phd, masters, computer-science, transfer-student, international

Have a question. Is it possible to start phd in a particular stream and then transfer to masters in a different stream ? OR if someone is pursuing phd can they apply for other masters program which are of more interest to them then their current phd ?
Also if one desire to switch the field in which they originally enrolled to do PHD.
All questions as they relate to international students.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which country? I am used to PhD students already having a master's degree, in which case this reduces to the question of getting another master's.

Comment: I would say this might depend on the stream as well. Your question would be cleared if you mention which streams you are referring to in the question body. Also, the word 'transferring' seems confusing here, as you are talking about two different degree levels and two different streams.